# prevent sleep mode and automatic update/shutdown - windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I need to run a program - probably for a couple of days.

I am just wondering how I can prevent windows 7 to go into sleep mode/hibernate and prevent automatic update.

Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Or you can just right click on the power icon near the clock, or type power in the Start Menu and select power options. Next choose one of the currnet power plan your computer is set to, and click on the Change plan settings. Simply set ALL the parameter to Never... you computer will run forever...

There are [two great sample chapters](http://www.learningwindowsphone.com/preview.html) on Windows Phone and Silverlight for Windows Phone on the [LearningWindosPhone.com](http://www.learningwindowsphone.com/) site. There is great Windows [Phone Trainng material](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/WP7TrainingKit/) , and dont forget the [Windows Phone Develoeprs Blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/wpdev/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As for preventing sleep/hibernate try to look in MSDN at SetThreadExecutionState, WM_POWERBROADCAST. Read also the [following document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/PM_apps.docx).

Comment: sorry is this done on the OS level or programmatically. I would like to set it on the OS level.

Comment: actually this was quite helpful:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions

Comment: The link above is dead. So sad.